# TypeError: firebase.firestore () is not a function web javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image on firebase cloud storage with web javascript. I am getting "firebase.firestore () is not a function" on my console. Am I going any wrong way?

I have done insert and fetch data on firebase database. But I have to stop for upload image on firebase cloud storage.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XXX",
        authDomain: "XXX",
        databaseURL: "XXX",
        projectId: "XXX",
        storageBucket: "XXX",
        messagingSenderId: "XXX",
        appId: "XXX"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    var defaultProject = firebase.initializeApp (firebaseConfig);
    // Get a reference to the database service

     var fileName = selectedFile.name;
     var storageRef = firebase.firestore ().ref ('image' + fileName).put (selectedFile);
```

Comment: do u have space between `firestore` and `()`?

Comment: Yes, NetBeans is given by default space. Now i removed space between firebase.firestore(). But I got the same error.

Comment: Why don't you try to `console.log(firebase, firebase.firestore)` and check what is logged?

Comment: After console.log(firebase.firestore ()), i got multiple data as object. Means there is no problem with "firebase.firestore ()". But when i write code firebase.firestore().ref() i got this kind of error.

Comment: It seems you've confused Cloud Firestore with Cloud Storage.  They are different products.

Answer (score 0):

updating node on the computer seemed to have fixed the issue. I updated it to v16.15.1

Answer (score -1):

change

```
 firebase.firestore ().ref ('image' + fileName).put (selectedFile);
```

to

```
 firebase.storage().ref('image' + fileName).put (selectedFile);
```

Comment: @PravinSharma, do you use storage instead of firestore ?

Comment: I want to upload an image on firebase storage and then get uploaded image URL.

Comment: @PravinSharma  ,this an example code , work for me:  var file = e.target.files[0];
      ```  //Create a storage ref
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('photos/' + file.name);
        //Upload file
        var task = storageRef.put(file);```

Comment: I have to do any setting on firebase console?